# How to add <a> to this element

Tags: html, css

Okay so I have a really interesting bug,

I'm using a navigation. This is pure HTML & CSS.

However it has a lot of pseudo properties and because of that I cannot use the  tag in that div.

```
 <div class='box curmudgeon'>
    <a href="#" class="nocolorrr">Housing</a>
    </div>
```

So the link won't work due to the pseudo properties,

```
  .box:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,160,80,0);
  color: #FFF;
}

.box::before, .box::after {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 3;
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s;

}


.curmudgeon::before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.curmudgeon::after {
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.box:hover::after, .box:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

Is there any fix? I have tried many things so far and have failed miserable. This is a new doubt for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the link a `z-index` higher than 3, and for `z-index` to work, it also need a position other than `static`, i.e. `position: relative`.

```css
.box a {                      /*  added rule  */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

.box:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 160, 80, 0);
  color: #FFF;
}

.box::before,
.box::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.curmudgeon::before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

.curmudgeon::after {
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.box:hover::after,
.box:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class='box curmudgeon'>
  <a href="#" class="nocolorrr">Housing</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot. Do you mind explaining me a bit about z-index? I really have read a lot about it but cant seem to understand the main concept?

Comment: @Adis When 2, or more, elements have the same position (x/y) they overlap each other, and with `z-index` you can control which one to be on top and which to be at bottom....like with your birthday cake, with whipped cream on top and jam between :)

Comment: Damn. I wish all books used this analogy. Amazing work. Loved it. Perfectly clear. Thanks for helping me out again mate. Really appreciate it.